# Mixing extension methods, generics and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, haskell, lambda

I'm porting Haskell's/LiveScript `each` function to C# and I'm having some troubles. The signature of this function is `(a → Undefined) → [a] → [a]` and I work very well with typing and lambda expressions in Haskell or LS, but C# makes me confused. The final use of this extension method should be:

```
String[] str = { "Haskell", "Scheme", "Perl", "Clojure", "LiveScript", "Erlang" };
str.Each((x) => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

And, with this, My output should be:

```
Haskell
Scheme
Perl
Clojure
LiveScript
Erlang
```

My current own implementation of `each` is:

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action closure)
{
  foreach (var result in list)
  {
    Delegate d = closure;
    object[] parameters = { result };
    d.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
  }
}
```

The problem is that here I just can't pass a parameter in my lambda expression. I can't do `(x) => ...`.

How can I pass parameters to lambda expression? It was very easier to work with first-class-functions in Haskell than in C#. I'm just very confused.

For that who don't know `Each`'s implementation, it is used for side-effects, returns the own list and applies a closure iterating and passing each value of the list as an argument. Its implementation in PHP should be:

```
public static function each($func) {
  // where $this->value is a list
  foreach ($this->value as $xs) {
    $func($xs);
  }
  return $this->value;
  // Or return $this; in case of method-chaining
}
```

Can somebody help me? I searched for it but it isn't clear for me. [And I don't wish use Linq]

Comment: "I don't wish to use LINQ". Why? You're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Haskell doesn't have an `each` function - the example would use `forM_`: `forM_ str putStrLn`

Comment: `List<T>` also has a `.foreach()` method where you can use delegate of  string as well

Comment: Sorry. I mean Haskell in concept of `each`. I work both with LiveScript and I use `each` so much.

Comment: I don't want to use LINQ because I **really** want to learn its implementation. I really need to **learn**.

Comment: Why create an extension method when you can just use `foreach`.  See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for why having a sequence operator with side-effects is considered bad.

Comment: Because I ported PreludeLS to PHP and now I'm porting it to C#. http://www.preludels.com/

Comment: For no side effects we have `map`.

Comment: If you want to learn how Linq is implemented I recommend Jon Skeet's [Edulinq](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/)

Comment: `Tony` there are a lot of good questions here.. basically at the end of the day we are all wondering `Why reinvent the Wheel`

Comment: I really love abstraction and expressiveness and I aim to give to C# a bit more of it. :3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need an `Action<T>` instead of an `Action`. You can also invoke it directly instead of using `DynamicInvoke`:

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> a)
{
  foreach (var result in list)
  {
    a(result);
  }
}
```